# Where do PHP variables point to so I can change them

Tags: php

I imagine this is very simple... I am a .NET developer trying to get a php site working on my dev machine, I have Apache, MySQL, phpMyAdmin and PHP all setup and working on Windows OS and the site loading on localhost but showing errors down to what I imagine are incorrect settings from the previous installation.

My issue is that I don't know what the following refer to:-

```
Setting::set("db_host" , $_SERVER['DB_HOST']);
Setting::set("db_name" , $_SERVER['DB_NAME']);
Setting::set("db_user" , $_SERVER['DB_USER']);
Setting::set("db_pass" , $_SERVER['DB_PASS']);  

@define("ROOT", "../../");
@define("PROJECT_PATH", ROOT."../".$_SERVER["PROJECT_PATH"]."/");
```

Where are these settings found? I thought in Apache/php/php.ini but no. Any assistance would be appreciated.

*Added

The file structure is

```
[project_folder] - app - admin
                       - xml
                 - www - project
                       - xml
                       - [all site files]
```

The details I found were in [project_name]\app\admin\includes

Comment: Can you tell us more about the website (framework, cms...) and where did you find these configuration elements (which file) ?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea about any frameworks used and am assuming it is a bespoke CMS. I will update the question with other details.

Comment: Well. It doesn't look like a regular and standard framework or cms. Anyway, about your problem, I'm afraid that these variables could be instantiated anywhere in your project... Have you tried to override these variables with your own ? It's not the best way to do it, but if you can't find where this configuration has been made...

Comment: That was going to be my next approach, luckily it's only a dev environment. I will go through with site wide replaces to hard coded urls and see if that does the trick.

Comment: At least, try to add your own config file and load it just before you you these variables.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but would that be an apache or php config file and where should it be placed?

Comment: You can define these variables in a php file (settings.php for example) and upload it on your server. Then, include it wherever you need it. Ex : <?php
$_SERVER['db_type'] = 'mysqli';
$_SERVER['db_host'] = 'localhost';
$_SERVER['db_user'] = 'user';
$_SERVER['db_passwd'] = 'pass';
$_SERVER['db_name'] = 'dbname';
?> Again, it's not a good pratice, but a least you'll see if something's wrong with your database configuration

Comment: I guess they where present in the servers environemt on the Linux box (No good idea!). On Windows you can place them in the `.htaccess` file. But then you need to make sure that your `AllowOverride` directive in the apache.conf (or virtual host conf) is set properly to allow this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean the contents of `$_SERVER`? These values had been passed trough environment variables. I would check the .htaccess file, I expect something like:

```
SetEnv DB_USER username
...
```

in it. If those variables aren't set in `.htaccess` file (really?) then they might been available (or need to be available) in the global server environment, which would be very insecure. Look at `/etc/environment` then.

Comment: Do you have shell access?

Comment: Its a local installation on a dev machine so I have admin access to everything.

Comment: First thing I would do is `grep -rn DB_USER /path/to/project`. Do you see any assignments?

Comment: The dev installation is on a windows OS... is that not a UNIX command?

Comment: Ok, Do you have an IDE which can search for `DB_USER` in the project? Every IDE should be able to perform a search.

Comment: Searching the project for DB_USER shows me that it exists within the $_SERVER['...'] tags previously mentioned. I need to know how/where these server variables are set so I can change/create them.

Answer (score 0):

`Settings` is a class somewhere in your code. It will have a `static public function set` which sets the variable, probably in some global static variable, which is a horrible way of doing things.

`define` is used to define a CONSTANT. See the **[docs](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.define.php)**.